# how to achieve whats app (iOS version) notification handling after killing whatsapp by swipe up

Tags: ios, notifications, push, whatsapp

Till now after searching what i know is, in iOS , notifications cannot be handled, once the app is killed , and after that app is launched by tapping app icon.

i want to achieve what whatsapp does, i.e.

1) i kill whatsapp from multitasking swipe up.
2) i receive whatsapp 1 new message push notification.
3) then without launching whatsapp(through app icon or through notification) i disconnect mobile data/ wifi or any internet connection.
4) after disconnecting all connections, i launch whatsapp BY LAUNCHING IT FROM APP ICON(and not from notification).
5) then i find that those notification message is already shown at the top chat as the new message with message count.

Now, my concern is, how does whats app handle push notification, even after app is killed.

Comment: there is a special kind of notification for voip, when receiving it, app will be launched in background even user killed it manually. The rest (handling notification data) is done as usual.

Comment: @azimov : could you please explain it a bit more and share some documentation links?

Comment: Apple's documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html

Comment: I think sir @azimov is trying to suggest a feature called `Silent push notification` which enables your app to receive notifications in the background. Even if your app is not running, whenever a notification is sent, the system will wake up your app and will be on the background for receiving the notification.

Comment: @ujjwal, search for push kit .

Comment: @scar, silent push notification as per apple documentation doesn't work when user kills app (by swipe up).

Comment: @azimov, u are right they use push kit, but does apple allow use of push kit  for non voip use i.e. push notification like whats app in the scenario i mentioned where there is no voip related

Comment: Whatsapp is a VoIP app (to receive VoIP Push Notifications app must enable VoIP mode). As far as I know other type of notifications can't wake up app is if was killed by user.

Comment: @ShridharSawant can you find any solution i m facing same issue

Comment: @kirtimali , you can you background fetch method for remote notification. which wakes your app and lets you process data in background. But still it will not help you when your app is killed. Only apple pushkit allows you to wake app even when your app is killed. (eg. skype and watsapp use this feature which have voip in their app.)

Comment: @ShridharSawant thank you for reply.what did whatsup  when it had  no voip  functionality  i telling about older version whatsup

Comment: @kirtimali, right, however i did not needed this functionality before whatsapp had voip. thus i did not check how whatsapp worked before that. btw what functionality are you trying to implement

Comment: @ShridharSawant  we are trying that functionality when notification arrived while user mobile and wifi is off also user clear notification from notification center then user open app want that notification message

Comment: what's app has voip but is it not compulsory to report voip notifications on UI ?? and app gets banned for further notifications if its not reported? can we use VoIP notifications just to wake up the app and sync data in the background?

Comment: @SanaullahIrfan, You need to have VOIP feature in app for apple to approve your app for using VOIP framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PushKit is the only solution...

For ref:- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/PushKit_Framework/

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: @RohitAgre Please refer the following link :https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/PushKit_Framework/

Comment: I need solution for android

Comment: what's app has voip but is it not compulsory to report voip notifications on UI ?? and app gets banned for further notifications if its not reported? can we use VoIP notifications just to wake up the app and sync data in the background?