# iOS whatsapp ,receiving the Remote Notification,how did it stored all the message?

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, whatsapp

iOS whatsapp was kill,not in the launch,after receiving the Remote Notification,close all networks and then click the whatsapp icon to entry application,you can see all the Remote Notification had stored in the message list,include photo or video.I find Silent Remote Notifications could not do it,because app not in the launch,How did it achieve?

Comment: I imagine they are using Pushkit with silent notifications, so the app will be relaunched in the background when the notification is received even if you terminated it

Comment: maybe the payload of the notification has everything it needs to properly store the message without needing to download it from the server once the app is in the foreground

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to achieve whats app (iOS version) notification handling after killing whatsapp by swipe up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278649/how-to-achieve-whats-app-ios-version-notification-handling-after-killing-whats)

Answer (score 0):

PushKit is help to me,use the voip background Modes,and more detail to see the apple document,
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html
thank everyone.